# Javascript - Excluding Iframe when taking screenshot

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, screenshot

I have a widget that will be used in third party website based on inclusion of some script. On click of some button the widget will be loaded inside an `iframe` and inside the widget there is a button to take the screenshot. Here are parts of my code to take the screenshot.

```
jQuery(window).bind("message", function(e) {
  var data = e.originalEvent.data;
  loadCanvas(data);
});

function loadCanvas(dataURL) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("f-screenshot");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var imageObj = new Image();
  imageObj.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(this, 0, 0, 300, 220);
  };
  imageObj.src = dataURL;
  img_data = dataURL;
}
```

But in my screenshot the area where the iframe appears is shown in grey colour like this. 
[image]

How can I take the screenshot excluding the `iframe`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `data-html2canvas-ignore="true"` to all the elements which are not to be included in the screenshot.